# Call original gf after remapping gf to custom function

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, key-bindings

`gf` doesn't work for absolute links used in Azure DevOps yaml files, p.e.

```yaml
  - template: /devops/template/my-template.yml
```

(It only works without the leading slash.)

This is why I have created my [custom function](https://github.com/MaxGyver83/dotfiles/blob/c9a83fc3590c3d405da5102175a3c40fd71b1f84/vim/.vimrc#L669-L698) that tries first a `gf` and then tries guessing the file that is meant:

```
function! GoToFile()
    try
        normal gf
    catch
        let path = expand("<cfile>")
        if path[0] == '/'
            ...
        endif
    endtry
endfunction
```

I have mapped it to `gF`:

```
nnoremap gF :call GoToFile()<CR>
```

This is just a workaround. Actually, I would like to map it directly to `gf`:

```
nnoremap gf :call GoToFile()<CR>
```

But then strange things happen (after using `gf`):

- No syntax highlighting for the opened file.
- Other open buffers disappear from my "buffer tabs" (no real tabs, I use [ap/vim-buftabline](https://github.com/ap/vim-buftabline))
- The file name in the remaining "buffer tab" looks different now (`d/t/template.yml` instead of just `template.yml`)

Is something wrong with this approach? Do I end up in a loop? Shouldn't `nnoremap` prevent this? Is there a way to call the "original" `gf` (like `\ls` in bash to ignore aliases)?

Comment: The topic of calling the original version of a mapped command (like `command` in bash) came up a couple of days ago. Unfortunately, I can't find the question. The answer was that vim has no such feature. Hopefully, someone can post the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `normal! gf` with exclamation mark in your function.

With `normal gf` (without exclamation mark) you most probably are calling the same function over and over again until vim breaks it.

See `:h :normal`

```
            If the [!] is given, mappings will not be used.
            Without it, when this command is called from a
            non-remappable mapping (|:noremap|), the argument can
            be mapped anyway.
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is something wrong with this approach?

Yes.

When you do `gf` and Vim doesn't find the target file, it tries to use `:help 'includeexpr'`, if it is set, as a last resort. It is expected to be an expression that transforms the given "path-like" string into an actual usable path.

In this case, it would look something like this:

```
" in after/ftplugin/yaml.vim
setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname, '^\/', '', '')
```

which would let you use the native `gf` and `gF` and make this problem moot.

Now, `includeexpr` is supposed to return a valid path but it doesn't prescribe a way to do so. There are, actually, many situations where a substantial amount of work is required in order to obtain a valid path and that work can all be encapsulated in a function:

```
" in after/ftplugin/yaml.vim
function HandleAzurePaths(fname)
    " your code here
endfunction
setlocal includeexpr=HandleAzurePaths(v:fname)
```

If your logic in lines 677-694 works, you should be able to fit it there and make it return `x`… without having to deal with "real" `gf` and "fake" `gf`.

FWIW, I use such a function for JavaScript, where I reimplemented Node's module resolution algorithm in about 100 lines so don't feel constrained, here.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! While Maxim provided the quick and easy solution to what I wanted to do in the first place, this one seems to be "vimic" way of doing it. Probably I'll change my config to this one day.

Comment: Well, that's not really how I would describe the difference between the two answers but oh well